# pygame OpenGL windows not refreshing on Mac OS X 10.6, Python 2.7

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, sdl, pygame

I posted this on the [pygame mailing list](http://archives.seul.org/pygame/users/Nov-2010/msg00038.html) but maybe someone here will have an answer. I can't be sure whether it's a pygame problem or an SDL problem, really.

Essentially, I have some code that uses PyOpenGL and pygame to render rudimentary animations. It works fine under Linux but for some reason, the pygame windows on my Mac don't refresh unless I click outside the window to "unfocus", at which point they refresh once.

To install SDL and pygame I followed the [instructions here](https://superuser.com/questions/43531/installing-pygame-on-snow-leopards-system-python-2-6/53094#53094). I should note that

- 2D pygame examples such as `pygame.examples.aliens` work fine, while 3D ones such as `pygame.examples.glcube` exhibit the same problem as my own code.
- PyOpenGL demos work fine, so I'm assuming the problem isn't there.
- I also see this printed to the console:

  ```
  2010-11-12 00:31:51.328 python[75402:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): 
  Object 0x101da6570 of class NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in 
  place - just leaking
  ```

  Anyone know what that means?

Comment: The warning is probably unrelated, and I have seen this problem come and go on my Mac with programs written using all variety of OpenGL bindings…

Comment: Rebooting would sometimes fix the problem; it’s likely a driver issue or something infuriating like that.

Comment: Dammit! You're right. In particular, it seems as though Ctrl+C'ing a pygame GL process gets it into this nasty state and the only way to fix it is to reboot. Want to answer it so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out some sort of OS X driver glitch causes this when I Ctrl+C a pygame-based application, and the only fix is to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid its not a OpenGL problem. I had refresh problem in  both windows 7 and MACOSX 10.4.11 . For a strange reason no refresh problem on Linux.

What I did to solve this issue was to detect the "unfocus" event as the window had refresh problem only when it was unfocused and a window passed in front of it. As soon I detected the "unfocus" and / or "focus" even I issued a redraw of the whole window.

By the way I used none of the OpenGL binding or techniques, just standard pygame functions in particular the update function.

Comment: I think you were doing it wrong, then; a reboot fixed my problem.

Comment: I dont see how it is fault of my code as the problem appears in the lower half of the window while the upper half refresh fine by itself. And this problem does not exist in Ubuntu linux at all.